# Wand DelegateError after Reading Several Images

Tags: python, ghostscript, wand

I am reading images from a folder and searching the images for a specific pattern using openCV. Unfortunately after a few images I get the wand.exceptions.DelegateError below.  The number of images that are read before the error occurs varies wildly, sometimes it happens after 3 images sometimes after 20.

Error:

> File “/usr/local/python3.5/dist-packages/wand/resource.py”, line 222,
>   in raise_exception  raise e wand.exceptions.DelegateError:
>   FailedToExectuteCommand ‘”gs” -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE
>   -dNOPRINT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 “-sDEVICE=pngalpha” -dTextAlphaBits=4 “-r500x500”
>   “-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-29605oLlgPbxLwJy%d”
>   “-f/tmp/magick-2960EjsrSmTrJxjN” “-f/tmp/magick-2960f8G76Z8ZfzT1”’
>   (-1) @error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/461

I have attempted to run the code from the Terminal rather than through PyCharm as suggested in this post, however the error is still occurring: [Wand and ghostscript issue on PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141661/wand-and-ghostscript-issue-on-pycharm)

Here are some specifics for the my system:

- Oracle VirtualBox - Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5
- Wand 0.4.4
- ghostscript 9.18 (installed from repo)

Code:

```
for doc in PDFs:
    d+=1
    print('')
    print('Document:', '(', d, 'of', len(PDFs), ')', doc)
    #Create JPEG object
    image_pdf = Image(filename=path+doc, resolution=500)
    image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')

    req_image = list()

    #Create list of jpeg blobs for Pattern Scanning
    for img in image_jpeg.sequence:
        image_page = Image(image=img)
        req_image.append(image_page.make_blob('jpeg'))


    #Loop for processing each image in a PDF
    n=0
    for img in req_image:
        n+=1

        image_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(img), dtype=np.uint8)
        if image_buffer is not None:
            cv_img = cv2.imdecode(image_buffer, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Has anyone experienced this error?  I am confused as to why the process works initially for several documents but seems to randomly generate an error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suspect that your running out of OS resources, and ghostscript is not able to allocate more memory. A pdf of `resolution=500` would create a large raster, and the script above keeps ~5x copies in RAM. Are you able to run the script through a memory profiler?

Comment: I'm actually deleting some of the larger objects like image_pdf, image_jpeg and imag_page after I've used them,  I removed the deletions to make the code a little easier to read.   However,  your comment on resolution was correct,  changing to resolution = 200 has fixed the problem.  Thank you so much emcconville!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use pycharm to convert the images first then you can read that images in any IDE .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).